# How to capture numbers followed by spaces with forward slashes using preg_match_all?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture the following format `1 1/4` into the same key value from the preg_match_all return.

This is what I came up with:

```
<strong>1 1/2 lbs</strong> fish
<strong>⅛ cup</strong> peppers
<strong>1-2 tbsp</strong> olive Oil

preg_match_all("/[\d+↉½⅓⅔¼¾⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚⅐⅛⅜⅝⅞⅑⅒⅟](?:\/\d+?)?(?:-?\d+)?(?: \/\d+)?/u", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

It outputs:

```
0 => array(
    0 => 1
    1 => 1/2
    2 => ⅛
    3 => 1-2
    )
)
```

But it should be:

```
0 => array(
    0 => 1 1/2
    1 => ⅛
    2 => 1-2
    )
)
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/lHv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?:[ \-\/]*[\d↉½⅓⅔¼¾⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚⅐⅛⅜⅝⅞⅑⅒⅟]+)+
```

matches your example and matches strings like

```
<strong>15½ cup</strong> peppers
<strong>14½-17 cup</strong> peppers
<strong>15 1/2 - 16    tbsp</strong> Oil
<strong>1½</strong> Oil
```

too.

And if you want to avoid a double match for `<strong>1 1/2 lbs</strong> f15h` you can check for the "strong" tag with a positiv lookbehind

```
(?<=<strong>)(?:[ \-\/]*[\d↉½⅓⅔¼¾⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚⅐⅛⅜⅝⅞⅑⅒⅟]+)+
```

Comment: I am so lame, you're not.